# is there any text-independent features in voice print

Tags: artificial-intelligence, signal-processing, speech-recognition

I am new to the speech and speaker recognition probleme I understanded the way mfcc works but as far as I understanded (and found ) the coeffecients vary between the different words . my question : is there any other feature extraction methods that are text independent ? if so please refere to them . 
Any hint will be very helpful . 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by *text-independent*. MFCC (and any other) feature is a vector of real coefficients. Similar audio frames (in terms of human perception) may give you similar coefficients, but they also may not. If we speak of speech recognition then background noise and individual voice characteristics can change the coefficients drastically. That's why classifiers such as GMM or DNN are used to determined speech units given a particular MFCC. If you're interested in other feature extraction algorithms you can read about LPC and PLP features.

Comment: thanks a lot and sorry for the Inconvenience . if I am to reformulate my question . I am trying to create a speaker not a speech recognizer thus I am more concerned about the results being similar for the same speaker speaking many different sentences I have tried the MFCC using ANNs as my classifier but the results were not very promising also I don't think it will be good enough for voice conversion which is also another goal  . so what is the less variant method  for feature extraction given a single speaker and many different sentences ? again thanks in advance .

Comment: For speaker recognition search for "i-vectors".